# Is there a way to access a defined function by adding its name in the form of a string and executing it later?

Tags: javascript

I know that functions are objects, and objects never equal each other, even if they are identical. The question that I have is that, let's say I have a function as follows:

```
const xyz = () => a + b;
```

Can I access this function **somehow** using this code below or something similar:

```
const func = `x + y + z`;
```

And then later execute it like a normal function? Is there a library or tool that I can use?

```
func()
```

I am using Javascript.

I am building a small project and am importing functions from a file where they are already defined. I want those functions to run when a user clicks a specific button. The text of the button plus an additional string can be joined to make the name of that fucntion. Now I want to run that function using the name but it ends up in error.
Here is the code of what I am trying to do.

```
import "./style.css";
import tabs from "./tab.js";
import {biryaniTabChange, pulaoTabChange} from "./dishTexts.js";


tabs.heading();
tabs.createTab();
tabs.appendDish("Biryani");
tabs.appendDish("Pulao");
tabs.appendDish("Aloo Matar");
tabs.dishDiv();
let dishes = document.querySelectorAll(".dishes");
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (!e.target.classList.contains('dishes')) return;
    if (!e.target.closest('div').classList.contains('tabs')) return;
    let func = new Function(e.target.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '') + "TabChange");
    console.log(func);
    e.target.addEventListener('click', func())
})
window.onload = () => {
    biryaniTabChange();
}
```

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ please give some context what you really want to do

Comment: I am importing functions from a file where they are defined in a way that I can combine two strings to get them. Now I am trying to get them by combining two strings; however, it ends up in an error that `it is not a function.` That is why I asked if there is a way to get a function by joining two strings.

Comment: Do you use `import` statement to import them?

Comment: Yes. I am using `import` to import them.

Comment: I don't see where do you import the functions.

Comment: `import {biryaniTabChange, pulaoTabChange} from "./dishTexts.js";`

Comment: `import * as fns from './dishTexts.js` -> `fns['biryaniTabChange']` -> `fns[e.target.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '') + "TabChange"]`, this is how you can access the function

Comment: Btw, "*let me know and I will delete this question*" will not prevent the platform from rate-limiting your questions.

Comment: Your code would kinda work if you did use `eval` - the `new Function` will be created in the global scope and evaluating it won't find the module imports. But it's much better practice anyway to refer to the functions directly by name, as part of an object or `Map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First import every function into one namespace object:

```
import * as fns from "./dishTexts.js";
```

Then you can access them by name with the string:

```
const name = 'biryaniTabChange'
fns[name]()
```

or just

```
fns['biryaniTabChange']()
```

And your final code will look something like this:

```
const name = e.target.textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '') + "TabChange"
const func = fns[name]
e.target.addEventListener('click', func) // no call here!
```

Based on the sample you provided

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I really appreciate it. I should've paid more attention to the ways of importing functions from other files.